# Componente ListView só é exibido a partir da metade para baixo da tela

Tags: xamarin-forms

A questão é a seguinte:

Tenho um *ListView*, dentro de uma "*ContentView*", ela é populada adequadamente e o template aplicado normalmente como esperado.

Estou dentro de uma navegação "*Master-detail*" e neste caso, a *ContentView* é invocada de dentro de uma "*ContentPage*", que é a página detalhe de *Master-Detail*, onde filtra a opção escolhida no menu *Master* e exibe o conteúdo à esquerda.

Normal, todo mundo conhece esse funcionamento.

O que ocorre é que há outra *ContentView* que é chamada de outro menu e suas *views* são exibidas adequadamente ambas aninhadas num *SrollView* e *StackLayout*, sendo que numa delas o *ListView* é exibido inteiro, só que ele é posicionado da metade para baixo, sendo que não há *View* nenhum.

Observação: Depois que coloquei um *Entry*, este foi exibido acima. Como pode isso?

Observação 2: Os *VerticalLayouts* e *HorizontalLAyouts* da visa estão inseridos em suas posições.